# Which Material Design Framework is best for Phonegap Android?

Tags: cordova, angular-material

i decided to use one of material frameworks in my next Cordova Phonegap Project.
but i don't know which one is best for phonegap and works fine in older android versions.
Polymer, Materializecss, Angular Material and...  Which one is best for Phonegap & Android?

Comment: Well, Google itself made a material design implementation for the web (HTML and JS)! And it's called [Material Components Web](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://ionicframework.com/ its like Phonegap but you use Angular. You have multiple options with material design and ionic.
I am going to test this one soon http://ionicmaterial.com/

Comment: i want to know which one of material design frameworks is best for older android version. i don't want switch to ionic for material design

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Cordova + JQuery, the best frameworks are Material Lite, but if you're going to user Cordova + AngularJs, you should use Angular-Material.

If you're going to user Cordova + AngularJs + Angular-Material, you can get a seed here:
  https://github.com/marioaleogolsat/cordova-angular-angularMaterial-seed

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the reason. Also, why would you choose to discard such choice as materializecss ?

Comment: Angular-Material when using Cordova + AngularJs because Angular-Material is made for Angular, so it's optimized for it, I've used it and it was amazing.
About Cordova + JQuery, I don't like JQuery, but my friend do and he liked both MaterializeCSS and Material Lite. I didn't said about MaterializeCSS, because the documentation was a little... poor and it's wasn't so "Material", Material Lite was better at both things, about the documentation and the Material Design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle new framework Mobile Application Framework (MAF) this can be integrate on IDE like eclipse or JDeveloper and its an open source framework so its free of cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Onsen-UI](https://onsen.io/v2/), you will learn it fast, supporting on stackoverflow and their website is great, there are a lot of working editable example on their site, and they have theme builder too.

Answer (score 0):

For Material Design Experience (mostly for Android Apps) you can use these two frameworks,

1. AngularJS + Material Design+ Phonegap/Cordova = Angular Material (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) (Personal Favorite)
2. Polymer + Phonegap/Cordova (https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/)

Answer (score 0):

This might be late to answer but Framework7 is also a very good option.
It supports Material Design for android and iOS Layout for iOS.
It's developer friendly, sugar syntax, Great support and also supports Vue.js and React.js(Soon) out of the box.

Take a look at http://framework7.io/

Comment: Most importantly to me, I found F7 to perform significantly better compared to others. Make sure to test on slightly older phones, not just the latest "octacores".