# Make a hybrid app with native look and feel

Tags: android, material-design, native, hybrid

I really like hybrid apps idea but I also really like android's native material design look and feel. I was just wondering if anyone knows any framework to look like Google's Material Design with HTML and Cordova? I just want a template that looks like native android app with Material Design.

Comment: As far as I know, React Native, Xamarin, and possibly others **do** provide material design components. Have you *tried* any of them?

Comment: I will try each one of them and keep you updated. Thanks

Comment: React Native seems good but is complicated. I would like to build a html app and compile it with phonegap. I want the template of the html to look like a native app.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881436/which-material-design-framework-is-best-for-phonegap-android

Comment: Yes but there is no great answers to it ;)

Comment: Ionic seems to be an enough of an answer

Comment: Not really, it looks hybrid not native. I want something hybrid but to look and feel like native, solid, material design...

Comment: You can choose your CSS framework and components, yes? How would you design a Material website? Something like Polymer? Material Design Lite? Material is just a design concept, not really something that limits you to a framework.

Comment: I know but for building apps, it is different than a website. Take a look at gmail for example, look at the ripple effect on the menu, the more options, the material design in it. It is differen than MDL or Materialize...

Comment: As far as I know, Gmail is a native app. Probably because Google has enough engineers to maintain both Android and iOS versions

Comment: I know that. But I meanthe design in it is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

[Material Components Web](https://www.github.com/material-components/material-components-web) is the best one... I changed my answer because it's new and it wasn't there before. I made a wordpress theme for MDC and I may release it soon. Showcase: http://toufic.000webhostapp.com/

---

### Original answer

Angular Material is really the best after doing some research!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Apache cordova for hybrid apps. Also, you can use [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) that make beautiful views with beautiful components (most of those component are based on material design) and if you don't like it, you can make your component!
Ionic framework is front-end that works with apache cordova.

**Good start!**

Comment: I am using cordova... I want to make something that looks native like gmail, hangouts and all the google material apps...

Comment: No, but ionic looks too hybrid... Do you have a showcase app ?

Comment: Of course! Eg: [App 1](http://blog.ionic.io/built-with-ionic-sworkit/) or  [App 2](http://blog.ionic.io/built-with-ionic-chefsteps/). See also: [Ionic Showcase](http://showcase.ionicframework.com/)

Comment: Ionic looks hybrid. Compare it with gmail or hangouts. The ripple effect on menu, the stabily........